# What is the equation of the circle

Tags: circles

I've been experiencing a difficulties in answering this. I hope someone will help me in solving this

Find the equation of the circle through the points $(2,8),(7,3)$ and $(-2,0)$.

Comment: Suan Welcome to MathSE. Can you show your attempts to solve this problem? For example, do you know the equation of the circle? Have you solved a similar problem? If yes, what did you learn?

Comment: Or if you know the general equation of the circle in 2D in terms of its center and $r$, you have $3$ variables and $3$ equations to solve.

Comment: I've been doing the elimination method, but still I couldn't get the right answer

Comment: If you were given a scale, compass and a pencil and 3 arbitrary points on a paper, How would you draw the circle? if you can answer this, applying the same algorithm would work as well (Hint: find the intersection of perpendicular bisectors of the lines formed by any 2 randomly chosen points)

Comment: @Suan I obtained the equation $(x-2)^{2}+(y-3)^{2}=5^{2}$ using hint of user.

Comment: @Anindya Prithvi, You're right. I deleted that answer. When I read the problem I accidentally changed the point $(2,8)$ to $(2,7)$ and thus solved the problem.
And I corrected that type and got $(x-2)^{2}+(y-3)^{2}=5^{2}$.

Comment: The general equation of a circle is $x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c$ =0 Try substituting the points and find g,f and c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The question can be restated as

> Given triangle $ABC$ with coordinates of vertices $A=(-2,0)$,
> $B=(7,3)$, $C=(2,8)$, find the equation of its circumscribed circle.

First, find the squares of the side lengths of $\triangle ABC$:
\begin{align}
a^2&=50
,\quad
b^2= 80
,\quad
c^2=90
\tag{1}\label{1}
.
\end{align}

Second, the coordinates of the circumcenter
is known to be found as

\begin{align}
O&=
\frac{a^2(b^2+c^2-a^2)\cdot A+b^2(a^2+c^2-b^2)\cdot B+c^2(b^2+a^2-c^2)\cdot C}
{a^2(b^2+c^2-a^2)+b^2(a^2+c^2-b^2)+c^2(b^2+a^2-c^2)}
\\
&=\tfrac1{12}\cdot(5\,A+4\,B+3\,C)
=\tfrac1{12}\cdot(5\,(-2,0)+4\,(7,3)+3\,(2,8))
=(2,3)
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

Third, find the radius:
\begin{align}
R&=|O-A|=|O-B|=|O-C|=5
\tag{3}\label{3}
.
\end{align}

Hence, the equation of the circle is

\begin{align}
(x-2)^2+(y-3)^2&=25
\tag{4}\label{4}
.
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Let $A(2,8),B(7,3)$ and $C(-2,0)$

Using, "$\perp$ line from centre bisects chord"

Midpoint of AC is $M_{AC}=(0,4)$

Midpoint of BC is $M_{BC}=\left(\dfrac{5}{2},\dfrac{3}{2}\right)$

Slope of line the lines AC and BC are $m_{AC}=2$, $m_{BC}=\frac{1}{3}$

and slope of perpendicular bisectors of AC and BC $m_1=-\frac{1}{2}$,$m_2=-3$,

and equation of perpendicular bisectors are $y=-\frac{1}{2}x+4$ and  $y=-3x+9$, respectively

Coordinates of intersection of perpendicular bisectors are $O(2;3)$ that is centre of the circle.

Radius is $r=OC=5$ or $r=OA=OB=OC$

$(x-2)^2+(y-3)^2=25$

Comment: (+1)Thanks for including this

Comment: Thanks a a lot.

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: How did you get the 9 in the y=-3x+9?

Comment: Using the point $M_{BC}$ and $m_2$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Let start from the general equation

$$(x-x_C)^2+(y-y_C)^2=R^2$$

and plug in the values $(x,y)$ for the given points to obtain three equations in the three uknowns $x_C$, $y_C$ and $R$.

We obtain the system

- $2x_1x_C+2y_1y_C-x_1^2-y_1^2=x_C^2+y_C^2-R^2$
- $2x_2x_C+2y_2y_C-x_2^2-y_2^2=x_C^2+y_C^2-R^2$
- $2x_3x_C+2y_3y_C-x_3^2-y_3^2=x_C^2+y_C^2-R^2$

that is

- $2x_1x_C+2y_1y_C-x_1^2-y_1^2=2x_2x_C+2y_2y_C-x_2^2-y_2^2$
- $2x_2x_C+2y_2y_C-x_2^2-y_2^2=2x_3x_C+2y_3y_C-x_3^2-y_3^2$

from which we can find $x_C$ and $y_C$ and then $R$.

---

We can check directly the solution $(x-2)^2+(y-3)^2=25$ you have obtaind as follows

- $(2,8) \to (2-2)^2+(8-3)^2=25$
- $(7,3) \to (2-7)^2+(3-3)^2=25$
- $(-2,0) \to (-2-2)^2+(0-3)^2=25$

Comment: I've been doing that lately, but still I couldn't guess the right answer. Could please show the solution?

Comment: @SuanSuan You should indeed show your work to better understand your difficulties.

Comment: I used online calculator in solving the equation and I get (x-2)^2+(y-3)^2= 25

Comment: @SuanSuan You can check it plugging in the given values.

Comment: @Suan Suan. Yes, that's the answer for your problem.

Comment: I used online calculator in solving the equation and I get (x-2)^2+(y-3)^2= 25 . 

But when I'm solving it using this method, this is what I get.
(2,8) (7,3) (-2,0)

x^2+y^2+Dx+Ey+F=0
For (2,0) 2D+8E+F=68
For (7,3) 7D+3E+F=58
For (-2,0) -2D+F=4
(b) = 7D+3E+F=58
(a) = -2D-8E-F=-68 +
(d)= 5D-5E=-10

(c) -2D+F= 4
(a) -2D-8E-F= -68 +
(e) -4D-8B=-64

4 (d) 20D-20E= -40
5 (e) -20D-40E= -320 + 
        -60E= -360 or equal E= 6

I substitute 6 in the (d), 5D+5(6)=-10, equal to D= 4
I substitute 4 in the (c),  -2(4)+F=4 , equal to 12

Comment: Let update your question with your full calculations, I’ll take a look to that later!

Answer (score 1):

Satisfy the general equation of circle
$$x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$$
with these  three points get linear equations in $f,g,c$ and solve them.